# Contact images cropped and downsampled when syncing with google contacts

Tags: contacts, sync, images, google-contacts

When Syncing with google contacts the photos I chose for my contacts are cropped to a square, and are downsampled to a very low resolution.

Is there a way to sync my phone contacts (without facebook), and keep the hi-res photos?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that contact picture quality varies widely with the dialer/contact app used. Consider trying a replacement like [GO Contacts EX](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jbapps.contactpro&hl=en) or any of the [other replacements in the market](https://market.android.com/search?q=dialer&c=apps).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried GO Contact EX and also other dialer, but the problem remains - once my contacts are synced with google contacts, the resolution drops and the image crops :(